# Generating HTML report for JTable data

Tags: java, html, swing, jtable, report

I need to generate report in HTML for my Swing based application.

- Is it possible to convert `JTable` into HTML code (HTML table)?
- If yes, how can I convert `JTable` into HTML table, or is there any alternative way to generate HTML for reporting?

Comment: If you can have this html in the most basic form - why not iterate over the `JTable`'s rows and build a `String` with `table`, `tr` and `td` html-elements wrapped around your data? But there might be some better possibilities.

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us.  Better in what way?

Comment: Better to be smart, than sorry.  The smart thing to do would be to fill in the details of 'better' as an edit to you question.  By details I mean "what features should this 'better' way have?" (that are missing from the suggestion by @Xeon - which seems pretty easy to me).

Answer (score 2):

Ok. I've come to three solutions over night (you can combine them if possible):

1. The basic - the most control and flexibility - you generate HTML by iterating over rows wrapping data with `table`, `td`, `tr`. For better visual effect you must manually include it in the generated output.
2. Create a model with [JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/tutorial/) or [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) annotations (or any library that provides you with easy JSON/XML creation) and save your model to/with a "html template" with fancy stuff like `CSS` and cool visual effects provided by for example `jQuery UI` (and extensions: [Heatbox](http://www.jnathanson.com/blog/client/jquery/heatcolor/index.cfm), etc.) [DataTables](http://datatables.net/), [KendoUI](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/grid/walkthrough.aspx), [Flexigrid](http://www.flexigrid.info/), or even [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery). To adapt to particular "visual-effects provider" you probably must manipulate a little your generated `XML`/`JSON` data but with `JAXB` you can even produce strict `HTML` `table` snippet.
3. Data generation like in `2.` - but you use this data with external tool/application that can read `XML`/`JSON` (or any format that you provided). You can try to use `Jasper reports` ([here](http://www.packtpub.com/article/jasperreports-creating-report-from-xml-data-using-xpath) and [here](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/xmldatasource/index.html), [iReport](http://jasperforge.org/projects/ireport), [Eclipse BIRT](http://www.eclipse.org/birt/phoenix/)) - the report tools should have option to `Save as..->HTML Page`.

In case of charts (and if you don't want above `JavaScript` based solutions) you can also generate images (that you will display in `HTML` page) with some java library that gives you the possibility to save generated images (for example [JFreeChart](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/) etc. or `Swing`'s paint components trick).